# how to use the loader<cursor> with my own adapter?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

I'm getting some errors when trying to implement loader manager for use with my content provider and DB.

**I'll start with logcat output:**

```
1-19 16:37:33.628: I/(20193): Loaded EGL implementation /system/lib//egl/libEGL_tegra_impl
01-19 16:37:33.648: I/(20193): Loading GLESv2 implementation /system/lib//egl/libGLESv2_tegra_impl
01-19 16:37:33.883: E/CursorWindow(20193): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 11 rows, 1 columns.
01-19 16:37:33.883: W/dalvikvm(20193): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cfc2d0)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at adapters.FastScrollAdapter.getView(FastScrollAdapter.java:99)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1520)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
01-19 16:37:33.893: E/AndroidRuntime(20193):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the fragment where the list should be displayed:

```
public class ShiftsFragment extends Fragment implements
            LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        public static Typeface tf, tf2, roboto;
        private FastScrollAdapter adapter;
        ListView ls;

        public static ShiftsFragment newInstance(String title) {

            ShiftsFragment pageFragment = new ShiftsFragment();
            return pageFragment;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shifts, container, false);

            /*
             * StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
             * .detectAll().penaltyLog().build()); StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new
             * StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
             * .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().detectLeakedClosableObjects()
             * .penaltyLog().penaltyDeath().build());
             */

            roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/JuraLight.ttf");
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/Advert.ttf");
            tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),
                    "fonts/passion.ttf");

            TextView SF = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.total);
            SF.setTypeface(tf);

            ls = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


            return view;

        }

        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
            // Query the db asyncronously

            String[] projection = { DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,
                    DBAdapter.KEY_TIMESTAMP_IN, DBAdapter.KEY_TIMESTAMP_OUT };
            String where = null;
            String[] whereArgs = null;
            String sortOrder = null;

            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                    provider.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

            return cursorLoader;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {

            // Update adapter and views // must use a handler to sync UI thread
            // stuff
            adapter = new FastScrollAdapter(getActivity(), arg1);
            ls.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
            // release references

        }

    }
```

**This is my content provider class:**

```
public class provider extends ContentProvider {

    private DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "provider";

    private static final String BASE_PATH = "todos";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
            + "/" + BASE_PATH);

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(getContext());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(getContext());
        dba.open();
        SQLiteDatabase db = DBAdapter.db;
        queryBuilder.setTables(DBAdapter.DATABASE_TABLE);

        Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**and here is my own custom adapter:**

```
// This is a custom adapter that will use cursor to get data from SQLite DB as the source.

public class FastScrollAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public static Cursor cursor;
    public static int c = 0;
    public static ViewHolder holder;
    public DBAdapter dba;
    Context context;


    public FastScrollAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cursor = c;
        this.context = context;

    }

    public FastScrollAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cursor = c;
    }

    // Here we shall look to see if the View already exists and create a new one
    // if not.

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        dba = new DBAdapter(context);
        this.cursor = dba.getAllShifts();

        int listLength = cursor.getCount();
        // If view doesn't exists = create a new one and also store it (all of
        // the views) in our ViewHolder class called "holder"
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.TL = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TableBG);
            holder.info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Info);
            holder.info.setTypeface(SettingsFragment.roboto);
            holder.info.setText("Info");
            holder.dateDisp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.dateDisp);
            holder.timeInShift = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.timeInShift);
            holder.day = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            holder.Money = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Money);
            holder.shiftDisp = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.shiftDisp);
            holder.start_finish = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.start_finish);
            holder.Duration = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Duration);

            holder.insert = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.insert);
            holder.insert.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            // If exists, just fetch this view and display it.
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        this.cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        // Set some values...
        /*************** Taken From DB ******************/
        holder.start_finish.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_START_TEXT_VIEW))
                + this.cursor.getString(this.cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_END_TEXT_VIEW)));
        holder.start_finish.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);

        holder.shiftDisp.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_MONEY)));
        holder.shiftDisp.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);
        //

        holder.dateDisp.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DATE)));
        holder.dateDisp.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);

        holder.day.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DAY)));
        holder.day.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);

        holder.timeInShift.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_TOTAL_TIME_OF_SHIFT_STRING)));
        holder.timeInShift.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);

        holder.insert.setText(this.cursor.getString(this.cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_INSERT_MODE)));

        //

        /*************** Regular ones ******************/

        holder.info.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);
        holder.info.setText("Date:");

        holder.Money.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);
        holder.Money.setText("Money Made:");

        holder.Duration.setTypeface(ShiftsFragment.roboto);
        holder.Duration.setText("Duration:");

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        return null;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView info;
        TextView dateDisp;
        TextView day;
        TextView Duration;
        TextView start_finish;
        TextView Money;
        TextView shiftDisp;
        TextView timeInShift;
        TextView insert;
        TableLayout TL;

    }

    public static void animate(final View v) {

        final Animation out = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        out.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        out.setDuration(350);
        v.setAnimation(out);
        out.start();
        out.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.i("Animation", "Started");

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                // Shifts.setSummaryCursor.requery();


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                // Shifts.setSummaryCursor.requery();


            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi guys, I'm getting some errors when trying to implement loader
>   manager for use with my content provider and DB

You're trying to access a column from the cursor in the `getView` method which doesn't exist in that cursor. I can't help you with something else because I don't know how you did the query(so check the columns that you use to get the String to be present in the query you make on the database).

Also, I would advise you to follow some tutorials about adapters, what you currently do in the `getView` method(querying the database) is absolutely horrific. And you probably don't need that query anyway as you should use the cursor returned by the loader(where you also set the adapter)

Comment: Hi thank you for your input. Would you care to explain more about whats wrong with my adapter?

Comment: @Yosi199 The problem is you're doing a database query to retrieve a cursor from the database in the `getView` method. As the `getView` method is called each time the list is scrolled you'll be doing a lot of database queries(which are slow). Also you use a `Loader` to get some data from the provider, only to throw it away by making the query in the `getView` method an replacing the `Cursor` returned by the `Loader`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'm sure it looks bad as this is the first time I'm using loaders.

Let me get this stright - in "onCreateLoader", I'm returning a cursorloader. how do I use it in my adapter?

Comment: I'm passing the cursor I got in the loader (arg1 in onLoadFinished) to my adapter class. Now in my adapter I use it to access the different columns and assign them to the designated views.

Please, show me how to change it in my code I would really appreciate it!

Comment: please read my previous comments and let me know if it's wrong that I pass the cursor from the loader callbacks to the adapter.

Comment: @Yosi199 Yes, that is the proper way. You create the `Loader` and make it return a Cursor with **all** the columns you'll need in the adapter. In the `onLoadFinished` method pass the Cursor to the adapter. In the adapter get the data from the cursor and assign it to your views. Are you having problems with this?

Comment: this is what I'm currently doing but you said the code looks horrific in the adapter and that I'm quering the DB again and ignoring the cursor returned by the loader. I really want to do it the right way so if you still think I'm doing something wrong I would like to know.

Thanks for your input

Comment: @Yosi199 have a look at your `getView` method. You have the adapter's Cursor that you set in the `onLoadFinished` callback but then you decide it to do `dba = new DBAdapter(context);
        this.cursor = dba.getAllShifts();` ... what is the point of this when you already have the `Cursor`?

Comment: Wow... I feel so stupid right now. Thank you, really thank you!